# Update multiple rows with different values in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table like this :-

```
Product ID            Weight
A                     100
B                     100
C                     100
D                     100
E                     100
```

I want to change it to:-

```
Product ID            Weight
A                     501
B                     601
C                     701
D                     801
E                     401
```

How can I do that with SQL update command ??

Answer (score 8):

Use Case expression like this

```
UPDATE products SET
Weight = 
CASE ProductID
   WHEN 'A' THEN 501
   WHEN 'B' THEN 601
   WHEN 'C' THEN 701
   WHEN 'D' THEN 801
   WHEN 'E' THEN 401
END
WHERE ProductID in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
```

Without the WHERE clause, every row in the table would be tested (unnecessarily, since they will never match).

More info: [CASE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx), [Case Oracle](http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/), [Case MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html)

Comment: Hi, 

I tried to do that with some extra :-

UPDATE products SET
Weight =
(CASE ProductID
   WHEN 'A' THEN 501
   WHEN 'B' THEN 601
   WHEN 'C' THEN 701
   WHEN 'D' THEN 801
   WHEN 'E' THEN 401
END)
where Store = 'HHH' and Company = 'ABC'

The system prompted with the following error message:-
Error: SQL0199 - Keyword WHERE not expected. Valid tokens: SET. (State:37000, Native Code: FFFFFF39)

Comment: What RDBMS is used? (SQL SERVER, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL)

Comment: According to Error SQL0199 looks like you are using DB2

Comment: After i hv removed the brackets, it prompted with another error code:-
Error SQL0407 - Null values not allowed in column or variable Weight

Comment: Ok, table products contains some  additional productIDs (not only A, B, C, D, E). So you should add ELSE statement for this case. (Example, 
CASE ProductID
   WHEN 'A' THEN 501
   WHEN 'B' THEN 601
   WHEN 'C' THEN 701
   WHEN 'D' THEN 801
   WHEN 'E' THEN 401
   ELSE 100
END)

Comment: It works well (for the ELSE) based on the assumption that the other productsIDs are 100. If I wish not to change to 100 but to maintain its origin value of the other productIDs, what should I do then ?

Comment: You should leave old weight ( CASE ProductID WHEN 'A' THEN 501 WHEN 'B' THEN 601 WHEN 'C' THEN 701 WHEN 'D' THEN 801 WHEN 'E' THEN 401 ELSE Weight END)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE [TABLE] SET Weight = 501 WHERE [Product ID] = 'A'
GO
UPDATE [TABLE] SET Weight = 601 WHERE [Product ID] = 'B'
GO
UPDATE [TABLE] SET Weight = 701 WHERE [Product ID] = 'C'
GO
UPDATE [TABLE] SET Weight = 801 WHERE [Product ID] = 'D'
GO
UPDATE [TABLE] SET Weight = 401 WHERE [Product ID] = 'E'
GO
```

Comment: This is for single row but I hv multiple rows. How to do that ?

Comment: UPDATE [TABLE] SET Weight = 501 WHERE [Product ID] = 'A'
UPDATE [TABLE] SET Weight = 601 WHERE [Product ID] = 'B'
UPDATE [TABLE] SET Weight = 701 WHERE [Product ID] = 'C'
UPDATE [TABLE] SET Weight = 801 WHERE [Product ID] = 'D'
UPDATE [TABLE] SET Weight = 401 WHERE [Product ID] = 'E'

I hv run one at a time. I cant execute them together ? Is there a way to run them concurrently.

Comment: They will never run concurrently, update performs one row at a time. Why is that important?

Comment: I hv thousand of rows to update. There must be a way to shorten the process. I cant be sitting here the whole day just to run row by row.

Comment: Thousand of rows shouldn't take more than seconds or minutes. There must be something else whats wrong. How much time does one update take? What does the Execution Plan look like?

Comment: What I meant earlier was after inserted the SQL statements :-

UPDATE [TABLE] SET Weight = 501 WHERE [Product ID] = 'A'
UPDATE [TABLE] SET Weight = 601 WHERE [Product ID] = 'B'
UPDATE [TABLE] SET Weight = 701 WHERE [Product ID] = 'C'
I clicked Execute button. It prompted an error msg:-
Error: SQL0199 - Keyword UPDATE not expected.
Next, I ran the above statement one at a time ie.
UPDATE [TABLE] SET Weight = 501 WHERE [Product ID] = 'A'
clicked execute button
UPDATE [TABLE] SET Weight = 601 WHERE [Product ID] = 'B'
clicked execute button
That's what I meant, one at a time.

Comment: It doesn't work for the GO in between. Prompted with the same error msg.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? Do you use the management studio of SQL server?

Comment: You might want to try Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express, it's free and doesn't have these problems link:http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b